# How to avoid duplicate data in one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

Consider a following case:

there is an `Action` table, which has fields - `id`, `start_time`, `end_time` and `group_id`.

there is an `ActionGroup` table, which has fields - `id`, `start_time` and `end_time` of a group of multiple actions(Please note that actions occur sequentially).

`ActionGroup` has 1-to-many relationship with `Action`.

---

for example:

if there are four `Action` records,

[image]

the relevant `ActionGroup` record will look like

[image]

---

It seems that `Action` table already includes the data that `ActionGroup` table needs, and `ActionGroup` is actually repeating it.

Is it possible to query start time and end time of the `ActionGroup` in a simple and performant way, without separately logging the `start_time` and `end_time` fields inside `ActionGroup`?

Also, is it considered a bad practice to duplicate the data as in above case when designing a table schema?

Comment: I don't understand your `Action` table, nor does it appear to have a primary key.  Maybe include some sample data which helps to explain what your problem is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay, I'll come up with a diagram

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added an example, could you take a look?

Comment: You don't say when a row goes in a table in a situation--how can we say whether there is duplication, ok or not? Can one table be expressed in terms of the other? How did you get "the relevant ActionGroup record"? When giving (base or query result) relation(ship)s/associations or tables say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table.

Comment: @philipxy my bad, will keep in mind next time, and will try to polish up this question as well soon. thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your last question: Data duplication is bad in that it introduces the risk of inconsistency, e.g. if your `ActionGroup` 1 is registered with an `end_time` of (say) 8 while having an `Action` with `end_time` 13. If your data is inconsistent, you can't trust any query results, since an inconsistent logical system can produce any result at all.

In your example, `ActionGroup`can be derived from `Action` using an aggregate query (relational algebra pseudocode):

```
Action group by { group_id } add {
  Min(start_time) start_time,
  Max(end_time) end_time
}
rename { group_id id }
```

– so you don't need those attributes in the `Action` relvar (table). This is simple; whether it's fast enough depends on your requirements.

But note that if you do keep redundant `start_time`and `end_time` attributes in `ActionGroup`, you need to control the redundancy (preferrably with a constraint, alternatively with triggered actions, or, in the worst case, application code) in order to avoid inconsistency. This will also have performance implications, but they will apply to writes instead of reads.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think you need `ActionGroup` table from your example

From your example `Action` table already have all the information for ActionGroups (group_id, start_time, end_time)

You can just use `Action` table to get the min, max of start_time and end_time, but if you need more field on `ActionGroup` and get the start_time and end_time of Actions of the group try something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ActionGroup` as action_group
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT group_id, min(start_time), max(end_time)
  FROM ACTION
  GROUP BY group_id) as action
ON action_group.id = action.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that `Action` table already includes the data that
>   `ActionGroup` table needs, and `ActionGroup` is actually repeating it.

I think you are right, you are just repeating it based on your example. If you are only using `ActionGroup` to store the lowest (0) start_time and highest (13) end_time, since `Action` has already have group_id, you can easily get start_time or end_time by using

```
Select start_time in Action where group_id = '1' order by start_time;
```

Then `ActionGroup` have no purpose at all but if you are trying to achieve something more then I think it is a good idea to create `ActionGroup`.

For example:

> there is an ActionGroup table, which has fields - id, start_time and
>   end_time of a group of multiple actions(Please note that actions occur
>   sequentially).

If you have actions with a start_time: 4, 8, 2, 2, 10. Then we know 2 will be stored in `ActionGroup` but what `Action` it is? Then you can do something like start_time_id instead of start_time.

Here are some reading materials for creating tables that can help you:

[HOW TO DESIGN A SQL DATABASE](https://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/how-to-design-a-sql-database/)

[Database Structure and Design Tutorial](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/database-diagram/database-design)